# How to turn off SQLAlchemy implicit_returning?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to make insert query:

```
q_stat_insert = Stat.__table__.insert().values(insert_values)
res = Session.connection().execute(q_stat_insert, params)
```

but I have trigger on that table that returns NULL, how can I turn off RETURNING functionality?

Previously I've been avoiding this by simply using `__table_args__ = ({'implicit_returning': False})` in my class declaration.

P.S. I'm using Postgresql 9.4 and SQLAlchemy 0.9.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT` statements have an `inline` parameter which, when set to `True`, stops the implicit returning for a given statement. Set this parameter `inline = True` within your insertion statement to turn off the implicit return. It's worth noting that the default parameter scheme for an `insert` statement looks like this, which is why you must set `inline=True`:

```
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert(table, values=None, inline=False,
  bind=None, prefixes=None, returning=None, return_defaults=False, **dialect_kw)
```

This is documented [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/dml.html) for 0.9.